# Set value of list item based on last defined value in list

Tags: python, list, insert, append

I have a list of lists as follows.

```
ogList = [[a], [b], [], [], [c], [d], []]
```

I'd like each empty list to be populated like so, based on the last list which does have a value.

```
outputList = [[a], [b], [b], [b], [c], [d], [d]]
```

So far I have assembled the following.

```
copy = 0
for list in ogList:
    for list in list:
        for number in list:
            if number:
                copy = number
                print copy
            if not number:
                list.append(copy)
```

However append(copy) simply adds the value stored in copy to the second index of the list. Thus it occurred that I might use insert(0, copy), but this freezes up my system (infinite loop?). Here I am requesting assistance. How can I accomplish this?

I also greatly appreciate anyone willing to explain to this complete beginner what kinds of utter nonsense I might be employing here (like instantiating copy before the for loop?). Thank you everyone.

Comment: `list` is Python built-in, so try to avoid using it as the variable name. Also, it seems that you're still using Python 2+ version, why?

Comment: just propose another approach, please ask if any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ogList = [["a"], ["b"], [], [], ["c"], ["d"], []]

temp = ogList[0]
for i in range(1, len(ogList)):
    if ogList[i] == []:
        ogList[i] = temp
    else:
        temp = ogList[i]
```

If you use variables **a, b, c, d** in array instead of values **"a", "b", "c", "d"**, they must be assigned before array's assignment.

Don't use the same variable names in nested loops. That's why your program hangs.

Answer (score 1):

```
a=1;b=2;c=3;d=4
ogList = [[a], [b], [], [], [c], [d], []]

copy = 0
for index, list in enumerate(ogList):
    if list: #if list is not empty
        copy = list[-1] # last element
    else:
        ogList[index] = [copy]
print(ogList)
```

In your code, you went one level too deep (used too many for loops).

Also in Python lists are mutable, so when you tried to modify a list in a for loop, then only a copy of it could be overwritten, not the original one (`append()` is an exception to this). Generally, if you use indexes, you can overwrite the original values.

In my example I used the `enumerate()` function, which iterates over an iterable (e.g. a list), and returns an index and the value for it in each iteration. I can use the value to read, and the index to modify it.

In the else clause I completely overwrite the sublist, so I need to put `[` and `]` to indicate that `copy` is in a list.

Comment: I believe you don't need to use `enumerate` here.  Can access the item directly.

Comment: No, you can't, you can't modify the element. Please show me how you would do it. This does not do anything to ogList:
`for list in ogList: 
    if list:  
        copy = list[-1]  
    else:  
        list = [copy]`
off: how do you add line breaks to this kind of comment?

Comment: Well obviously you can do it like the others, with a for in range(len()) loop, but I find that ugly.

Comment: please see mine in next post, and  see how it can go w/o *range* or *enumerate*  Welcome comments.

Answer (score 0):

Not very Pythonic, but it works:

```py
og_list = [['a'], ['b'], [], [], ['c'], ['d'], []]

prev = []
for i in range(len(og_list)):
    if len(og_list[i]) == 0:
        og_list[i] = prev
    else:
        prev = og_list[i]

print(og_list)
```

Result:

```bash
[['a'], ['b'], ['b'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['d']]
```

Now let's go over your snippet:

```py
copy = 0
for list in ogList:  # cool
    for list in list:  # list in list? would be better to use something like sublist in list to avoid confusion
        for number in list:  # number? what if the inner list stores something that is not a number?
            if number:  # so basically if number is not None or False - why?
                copy = number
                print copy  # print(copy), you forgot the brackets (unless it's Python 2, in which case I have no idea about proper syntax, sorry)
            if not number:  # you could've used an else clause here, a number is or a number is not, these cannot be true at the same time
                list.append(copy)
```

The problem with your code begins at the `for number in list` line: this only iterates over elements of a sublist if that sublist itself is not empty - checks you tried executing inside that for loop were therefore useless (`if not number`, I assume, was supposed to check if a sublist is empty, but you'd never get here with an empty sublist).

Answer (score 0):

All earlier posts are working pretty well, but it seems that there are some room for improvements.

I find it more naturally to just loop and access directly the *original* list items **w/o** using *range* (and index) or *enumerate* here.  And I'm aware of it take some time for people from other languages...

So here just offer another simpler, maybe more ***Pythonic*** approach for your reference:

**Note** - this program will *only* work on the assumption that first item in the original list is not empty, as the sample input shown. Since the OP's requirement does not mention that situation.

```
ogList = [['a'], ['b'], [], [], ['c'], ['d'], []]

out = [ogList[0]]            # initialize to first item

#for i, lst in enumerate(ogList[1:]):   # only if you need idx, item
for lst in ogList[1:]:        # directly access the item, avoid idx
    if not lst:               # empty list encountered
        out.append(out[-1])   # add last item
    else:       
        out.append(lst)       # current lst
        

print(out)          # to confirm the output

# OR this easy way:
expected = [['a'], ['b'], ['b'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['d']]

assert out == expected          # silence, because they're same
```